# R contour plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour

I have a set of data in a gridded map and air pollutant concentrations for each grid.

```
x <- seq(1:12)
y <- seq(0.1,3,0.24)
set.seed(5)
z <- runif(length(x)*length(y),0,10)
data <- expand.grid(x,y)
data$z <- z
colnames(data)<-c("x","y","z")
p1<-ggplot(data)+
   aes(x = x, y = y, z = z, fill = z) + 
   geom_tile() + 
   coord_equal() +
   geom_contour(color = "white", alpha = 0.5) + 
   scale_fill_distiller(palette="Reds")+
   theme_bw()
print(p1)
```

[image: contour plot]

We can see the contour lines, but filling color not like smooth contour plot.

I've tried some example from website, they are working fine. I am just wondering, is this due to I have same lat for each raw and lon for each col? Any suggestion how can I fix it?

Comment: a. Your data is random, so it won't have a smooth gradient, and b. your resolution is 12 x 13, which will look pretty boxy unless it's really tiny. tl;dr: It's not your code, it's your data.

Comment: Maybe your data allows surface interpolation (like for example kriging) to get a bigger resolution.